# Add schema to Spark structured streaming messages in JSON format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm implementing a Spark Structured Streaming job where I'm consuming messages coming from Kafka in JSON format.

```py
def setup_input_stream(kafka_brokers, spark, topic_name):
    return spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_brokers) \
        .option("subscribe", topic_name) \
        .load()
```

I am then able to extract the `value` field from the Kafka message in the form of a String containing a JSON payload.

```py
deserialized_data = data_stream \
    .selectExpr("CAST (value AS STRING) as json") \
    .select(f.from_json(f.col("json"), schema=JSON_SCHEMA).alias("schemaless_data")) \
    .select("schemaless_data.payload")
```

Once I have this payload column, I'm struggling to find a way to let Spark automatically infer its schema and convert it to a proper `DataFrame`.

I know I can hardcode a `StructType` containing the schema of my payload, but  since I want to use this generic implementation to ingest data coming from different RDBMS tables (each table in its separate topic), I don't really want to hardcode the schema of every possible table.

Can message schemas be inferred somehow?

Comment: then only easiest thing I can imagine is get_json_object or schema definition using from_schema

Comment: By default auto schema inference is disabled im structured streaming .You can enable schema inference and then it should work